# How to select specific range of data column with C#

Tags: c#, datatable

I am trying to display several data, but I cannot select the column that I want. My code will produce all of the column data values. I have 9 columns in data table (zero-based), and I just want to get the data from column 3 till column 9. Grateful for any kind of insight!

```
foreach (DataColumn column in dt.Columns)
    {
        int i = dt.Columns.IndexOf(column);
        int colCount = dt.Columns.Count;

        for (i = 3; i < colCount; i++)
            {
                html.Append("<div class='col col-" + column.Ordinal + "' data-label='" + column.ColumnName + "'>");
                html.Append(row[column.ColumnName]);
                html.Append("</div>");
            }
    }
```

Comment: How do you fill your data table?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This answer including how to do what you want with Linq extension methods.

```
foreach (DataColumn column in dt.Columns.Cast<DataColumn>().Skip(3))
{
    html.Append("<div class='col col-" + column.Ordinal + "' data-label='" + column.ColumnName + "'>");
    html.Append(row[column.ColumnName]);
    html.Append("</div>");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem seems to be that you have two loops.
Wouldn't the below code achieve what you want?

```
int colCount = dt.Columns.Count
for (i = 3; i < colCount; i++)
        {
            DataColumn column = dt.Columns[i];

            html.Append("<div class='col col-" + column.Ordinal + "' data-label='" + column.ColumnName + "'>");
            html.Append(row[column.ColumnName]);
            html.Append("</div>");
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Check the snippet

```
        for (int i = 3; i < dt.Columns.Count; i++)
        {
            var column = dt.Columns[i];
            // more code
        }
```

Using LINQ you can achieve the same

```
        //This requires namespace using System.Linq;
        foreach (var column in dt.Columns.OfType<DataColumn>().Skip(3))
        {
            // more code
        }
```

Comment: Thank you So much! This is great!